# Windows 8 wallpaper rotates....occasionally

Tags: windows-8

I have Windows 8 and I have the wallpaper set to rotate every 5 minutes. I guess these are Microsoft minutes because I'll sometimes have the same wallpaper for 30 minutes, an hour, etc. It does eventually change but not nearly on the time frame that it should.

I've gone Google fishing but haven't found anything. I've tried to "kickstart" the process by changing it to say, 4 minutes and saving it back later, but no dice.

Do I need a 3rd party tool, or is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be related to your power plan's current settings. From a quick search on Google, I found [this tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5538-desktop-background-change-windows-8-a.html).
On the step **10. E)** of the second method to set the slideshow, they adjust the power plan settings.

To do the same go to:

**Advanced Power Settings -> Desktop Background Settings -> Slide Show**

and make sure that you have the **Setting** marked as **'Available'**.

If the problem persists after this change, you might want to consider a 3rd party tool similar to [EvJO Wallpaper Changer](http://www.evjosoft.com/WallChanger.html) (I've been using this software on my Windows 7 and it works just fine, but I don't know if it works in Windows 8).

Comment: Thank you. I checked that - it did say "Enabled" for being on a power source and I enabled it for battery settings just to be sure. If this doesn't work, I'll try your 3rd party tool.